# Objective-C Equivalent to string.unpack('N') in Ruby

Tags: objective-c, ruby, nsstring

I am trying to convert a string to a 32-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. In Ruby I accomplish this by `string.unpack('N')` - but can't seem how to manage this in Objective-C. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Note that Objective-C string objects are strictly for encapsulating properly encoded, typically UTF-8 or UTF-16, strings.   They should not be used for raw data (NSData is for that).  (I see lots of people coming from scripting languages confused on this point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective-C you would convert `NSString` to `NSData`. Then you can access the bytes from the `NSData` object.

```
NSString *str = @" H€llö Wòrld";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
// Output:
// <0001f604 00000020 00000048 000020ac 0000006c 0000006c 000000f6 00000020 00000057 000000f2 00000072 0000006c 00000064>

const uint8_t *bytes = [data bytes]; // pointer to converted bytes
NSUInteger length = [data length];   // number of converted bytes
```

Comment: Does it also care about endianess?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Yes, `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding` specifies big-endianess.